# SOAP PHP : how to translate request file to PHP function call

Tags: php, soap

I'm beginning with the SOAP lib of PHP and i can't figure out how to execute my request :

The server has a user friendly API which gives me the request to pass but i can't tell how I am supposed to do so.

Here is the point I currently am :

```
$soap = new SoapClient("https://www.dmc.sfr-sh.fr/DmcWS/1.5.6/MessagesUnitairesWS?wsdl");

$soap->getSingleCallCra();
```

and the request i should pass :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://servicedata.ws.dmc.sfrbt/">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <ser:authenticate>
   <serviceId>********</serviceId>
   <servicePassword>******</servicePassword>
   <spaceId>*******</spaceId>
   <lang>fr_FR</lang>
  </ser:authenticate>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ser:getSingleCallCra>
   <beginDate>2017-10-17T00:00:00</beginDate>
  </ser:getSingleCallCra>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The SOAP client does work for other function with no parameter but i get a translated java NPE exception when i call this function.

Can anyone tell me how i can pass the parameters and authentification to the function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$soap = new SoapClient("https://www.dmc.sfr-sh.fr/DmcWS/1.5.6/MessagesUnitairesWS?wsdl");
```

To add headers to a soapcall use the [__setSoapHeaders](https://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) method like this:

```
$soap->__setSoapHeaders(array(
  //(namespace, name, data)
  new SoapHeader("http://servicedata.ws.dmc.sfrbt/",'authenticate',array(
    'serviceId' => '********',
    'servicePassword' => '******',
    'spaceId' => '*******',
    'lang' => 'fr_FR',
  ))
));
```

These parameters will go into the soap body. In PHP you can use objects or associative arrays as input as they are both interpreted into xml as key => value pairs.

```
$soap_body_parameters = array(
  'beginDate' => '2017-10-17T00:00:00',
);

$response = $soap->getSingleCallCra($soap_body_parameters);

print_r($response);
```

The return value of the soapclient class is always an object, so remember to use the arrow notation '$object->property' to get the relevant data out.

## You can also create a class like this, that will deal with the headers, data extraction, etc. in the background for each call

```
class sfr_soap {
  function __construct($serviceId, $servicePassword, $spaceId, $lang = 'fr_FR'){
    $url = "https://www.dmc.sfr-sh.fr/DmcWS/1.5.6/MessagesUnitairesWS?wsdl";
    $this->client = new SoapClient($url);
    $soap->__setSoapHeaders(array(
        new SoapHeader("http://servicedata.ws.dmc.sfrbt/",'authenticate',array(
            'serviceId' => $serviceId,
            'servicePassword' => $servicePassword,
            'spaceId' => $spaceId,
            'lang' => $lang,
        ))
    ));
  }
  public function __call($name, $args = array()){
    $response = $this->client->$name($args);
    // do something with the response here, like extract the meaningful parts of the data
    return $response;
  }
}
```

init like this

```
$sfr = new sfr_soap($serviceId, $servicePassword, $spaceId);
```

or like this if you want to specify the language

```
$sfr = new sfr_soap($serviceId, $servicePassword, $spaceId, $lang);
```

use like this

```
$data = $sfr->getSingleCallCra(array(
  'beginDate' => '2017-10-17T00:00:00'
));
```

Comment: thank you it does work with this syntax of __setSoapHeaders(). Indeed I guess it will be better to call it in a constructor of an extended class.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to a SOAP function call multiple ways as it is stated in the documentation: [SoapClient::__soapCall](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)

> An array of the arguments to pass to the function. This can be either an ordered or an associative array. Note that most SOAP servers require parameter names to be provided, in which case this must be an associative array.

So in your case, the call should be:

```
$soap->getSingleCallCra(array(
   'beginDate'  => '2017-10-17T00:00:00',
));
```

I hope, I could be of any help.

Comment: Yes that what I thought but this doesn't solve the problem. Is it possible that the <ser:authenticate> part could be the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide an error message? It might help to solve your problem.

Comment: The error message was "java.lang.NullPointerException" (NPE) as the SOAP server basically throw the message of java. BTW the problem is solved by passing the correct header to the request.